# application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: not called ios 10.3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to develop a simple code which use push notifications. I create certificates and provision profiles based on existing tutorials, such as [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-push-notifications-for-ios-10/), and [this](https://makeapppie.com/2017/01/03/basic-push-notifications-in-ios-10-and-swift/), but the register function `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is not called at all, thus I can't get device token.

I also turned on Push notification and Remote notification for background in Capabilities tab in xcode. here is my code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}
```

[image]

I am working with an iPhone 5s running iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find why it wasn't called, but when I changed my test target to an iPhone 7 which is running iOS 10.3.2, it worked fine.

I'm not sure why it is happening, but changing your target may solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please call **registerForNotifications** from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in AppDelegate

```
 //MARK:- Methods
    func registerForNotifications(){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert,.sound]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }else{
                    print("Notification permission denied.")

                }
            }

        } else {
            // For ios 9 and below
            let type: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert,.sound];
            let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil);
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        print(token)

    }
```

Comment: it's not called again

Comment: Please delete your app and run it again. You will see the popup for authorization. You just need to allow your app to access push notification.

Comment: By seeing your attached image, You are only able to test it for development provisioning profile because you did not configure your push notification for distribution profile. I mean you just need to cross check your .p12 file, app id, provisioning profile with bundle id.

Comment: I deleted and installed again, popup appeared and I tapped on "Allow" button, but nothing has changed. I also checked my developer portal, it's OK. I just want to test this feature

Comment: There may be a configuration problem that causes a failed APN registration.

Assure that your Provisioning Profile contains the aps-environment entry
Assure that you have a unique App Identifier (a string without any "*") set in your Provisioning Profile. You should also use this exact identifier as "Bundle identifier" in your Info.plist
Maybe you have declined the Push-Feature after the initial installation - in this case you will never see the in-app-push-alert again and have to enable Push in the settings app again.
Try another device.

Comment: here is my appdelegate.swift file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=40002842074392647780
I checked my developer portal. everything seems fine. I have a provision profile containing Push-Notification feature enabled. I also have APN service certificate in the portal.

Comment: I test it on another iPhone (7), and it works. why? O_O

Comment: please add this method

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        if notificationSettings.types != .none {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

Comment: I think... the issue is in your device...not the code and other setup